# Use Geoserver's Barnes Surface SLD Transformation with an Geomesa

Tags: geoserver, sld, geomesa

I use Geoserver to post regular temperature points layer from an Accumulo/Geomesa dataset. I have to publish interpolated "temperature map" that's why I use SLD Transformation with an vec:BarnesSurface function.
This SLD works good for PostGIS datasource but for Accumulo/Geomesa shows white map and writes following to the Geoserver's log:

```
2017-09-27 10:28:48,862 DEBUG [org.geotools.process.factory] - Failed to locate the field 0.3 in class class org.geotools.process.vector.BarnesSurfaceProcess
2017-09-27 10:28:48,862 DEBUG [org.geotools.process.factory] - Failed to locate the field 0.3 in class class java.lang.Double
2017-09-27 10:28:48,862 DEBUG [org.geotools.util] - CRSConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to CRS  only.
2017-09-27 10:28:48,862 DEBUG [org.geotools.process.factory] - Failed to locate the field 2 in class class org.geotools.process.vector.BarnesSurfaceProcess
2017-09-27 10:28:48,862 DEBUG [org.geotools.process.factory] - Failed to locate the field 2 in class class java.lang.Integer
2017-09-27 10:28:48,863 DEBUG [org.geotools.util] - CRSConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to CRS  only.
2017-09-27 10:28:48,863 DEBUG [org.geotools.process.factory] - Failed to locate the field 0 in class class org.geotools.process.vector.BarnesSurfaceProcess
2017-09-27 10:28:48,863 DEBUG [org.geotools.process.factory] - Failed to locate the field 0 in class class java.lang.Double
2017-09-27 10:28:48,863 DEBUG [org.geotools.util] - CRSConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to CRS  only.
2017-09-27 10:28:48,863 DEBUG [org.geotools.process.factory] - Failed to locate the field -999 in class class org.geotools.process.vector.BarnesSurfaceProcess
2017-09-27 10:28:48,863 DEBUG [org.geotools.process.factory] - Failed to locate the field -999 in class class java.lang.Double
2017-09-27 10:28:48,863 DEBUG [org.geotools.util] - CRSConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to CRS  only.
2017-09-27 10:28:48,863 DEBUG [org.geotools.process.factory] - Failed to locate the field 1 in class class org.geotools.process.vector.BarnesSurfaceProcess
2017-09-27 10:28:48,864 DEBUG [org.geotools.process.factory] - Failed to locate the field 1 in class class java.lang.Integer
2017-09-27 10:28:48,864 DEBUG [org.geotools.util] - CRSConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to CRS  only.
2017-09-27 10:28:48,864 TRACE [org.geotools.factory] - ENTRY  (FeatureTypeFactory, FEATURE_TYPE_FACTORY)
2017-09-27 10:28:48,865 TRACE [org.geotools.factory] - RETURN (FeatureTypeFactory, FEATURE_TYPE_FACTORY): found implementation FeatureTypeFactoryImpl.
2017-09-27 10:28:48,865 TRACE [org.geotools.factory] - ENTRY  (FeatureTypeFactory, FEATURE_TYPE_FACTORY)
2017-09-27 10:28:48,865 TRACE [org.geotools.factory] - RETURN (FeatureTypeFactory, FEATURE_TYPE_FACTORY): found implementation FeatureTypeFactoryImpl.
2017-09-27 10:28:48,865 TRACE [org.geotools.factory] - ENTRY  (FeatureTypeFactory, FEATURE_TYPE_FACTORY)
2017-09-27 10:28:48,865 TRACE [org.geotools.factory] - RETURN (FeatureTypeFactory, FEATURE_TYPE_FACTORY): found implementation FeatureTypeFactoryImpl.
2017-09-27 10:28:48,865 TRACE [org.geotools.factory] - ENTRY  (FeatureTypeFactory, FEATURE_TYPE_FACTORY)
2017-09-27 10:28:48,865 TRACE [org.geotools.factory] - RETURN (FeatureTypeFactory, FEATURE_TYPE_FACTORY): found implementation FeatureTypeFactoryImpl.
2017-09-27 10:28:48,865 TRACE [org.geotools.factory] - ENTRY  (FeatureTypeFactory, FEATURE_TYPE_FACTORY)
2017-09-27 10:28:48,865 TRACE [org.geotools.factory] - RETURN (FeatureTypeFactory, FEATURE_TYPE_FACTORY): found implementation FeatureTypeFactoryImpl.
2017-09-27 10:28:48,865 TRACE [org.geotools.factory] - ENTRY  (FeatureTypeFactory, FEATURE_TYPE_FACTORY)
2017-09-27 10:28:48,865 TRACE [org.geotools.factory] - RETURN (FeatureTypeFactory, FEATURE_TYPE_FACTORY): found implementation FeatureTypeFactoryImpl.
2017-09-27 10:28:48,865 TRACE [org.geotools.factory] - ENTRY  (FeatureTypeFactory, FEATURE_TYPE_FACTORY)
2017-09-27 10:28:48,866 TRACE [org.geotools.factory] - RETURN (FeatureTypeFactory, FEATURE_TYPE_FACTORY): found implementation FeatureTypeFactoryImpl.
2017-09-27 10:28:48,866 TRACE [org.geotools.factory] - ENTRY  (FeatureTypeFactory, FEATURE_TYPE_FACTORY)
2017-09-27 10:28:48,866 TRACE [org.geotools.factory] - RETURN (FeatureTypeFactory, FEATURE_TYPE_FACTORY): found implementation FeatureTypeFactoryImpl.
```

I have checked valueAttr in my SLD. It has proper value. 
Any ideas?

**-----EDIT-----**

I think my problem is the way I load my data points into Geomesa/Accumulo. I use

```
List attributes = Lists.newArrayList(
  "GFS_TIME:Date",
  "PARAM_ID:Integer",
  "NAME:String",
  "TYPE:String",
  "TIMING:Integer",
  "RESOLUTION:Double",
  "VAL:Double",
  "*geom:Point:srid=4326"
);

String simpleFeatureTypeSchema = Joiner.on(",").join(attributes);
SimpleFeatureType simpleFeatureType = DataUtilities.createType(simpleFeatureTypeName, simpleFeatureTypeSchema);

simpleFeatureType.getUserData().put(SimpleFeatureTypes.DEFAULT_DATE_KEY, "GFS_TIME");

// ... prepare 2d array with my temperature data

// iterate 2d-array
// ...
      UUID uuid = UUID.randomUUID();
      id = uuid.toString();
      SimpleFeature simpleFeature = 
      SimpleFeatureBuilder.build(simpleFeatureType, NO_VALUES, id);

      simpleFeature.getUserData().put(Hints.USE_PROVIDED_FID, java.lang.Boolean.TRUE);

      simpleFeature.setAttribute("GFS_TIME", dt);
      simpleFeature.setAttribute("PARAM_ID", data.getParamId());
      simpleFeature.setAttribute("NAME", data.getParamName());
      simpleFeature.setAttribute("TYPE", data.getParamLevel());
      simpleFeature.setAttribute("TIMING", data.getParamTiming());
      simpleFeature.setAttribute("RESOLUTION", data.getParamResolution());
      simpleFeature.setAttribute("VAL", data.data[i][j]);

      double lat = 90 - j * data.getParamResolution();
      double lon = -180 + i * data.getParamResolution();

      GeometryFactory geometryFactory = new GeometryFactory();
      Geometry geometry = geometryFactory.createPoint(new com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Coordinate(lon, lat));

      simpleFeature.setDefaultGeometry(geometry);

      // accumulate this new feature in the collection
      featureCollection.add(simpleFeature);

// ... then load feature collection to Accumulo dataset
```

When I ingest similar data using geomesa command line tools it works with the same SLD file! May by my fields or geom definitions are wrong?

Comment: Starting with the output, is the white or empty map returning zero value results?  (One thing to check is if the results are scaled, say to between 0 and 1.)

Comment: When I execute vec:BarnesSurface WPS on my data directly (Geoserver->Demo->WPS) it results with an unreadable "no-data" tiff.

Comment: Posted some edits above

Comment: Since it sounds like data ingested two different ways is acting differently, it might be worth checking for any differences in the schemas (the geomesa get-schema command may help) and seeing if there are differences in the data (comparing a sample export).

One possibility is that one of the attributes names (e.g. NAME or TYPE) might conflict with some handling internal to GeoServer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GeoTools Rendering Transforms like creating a Density (Heatmap) and the BarnesSurface Process are handled in a rather special way when GeoServer uses them.

To see what is happening, I'd suggest firing up a debugger and stepping through the code.  From a quick look at the GeoTools code, it looks like one might be able to take what we've previously done for the DensityProcess and create a similar approach (https://github.com/locationtech/geomesa/blob/master/geomesa-process/geomesa-process-vector/src/main/scala/org/locationtech/geomesa/process/analytic/DensityProcess.scala).

Comment: Thanks! Finally I found that my grid resolution was too high for my current hardware architecture. When I decreased the resolution the process stopped dying. Currently I use Geodocker (Accumulo/Geomesa)+Geoserver for the test purposes.